# I am trying to access out parameters of a stored procedure (routine) in bigquery (gcp) from spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to access the **Out** parameter (which is an array of struct type ) of a stored procedure (routine) in the big query from Java Spring boot.
I am unable to find a way. There is a way to do it?

I am confused how to go about it. I have tried using the named parameter in the Queryjo configuration but it's not working. My procedure has no IN parameter only OUT,  when I simply call a procedure with no OUT parameter it's working
Example:

```
String query = "CALL my_dataset.my_stored_procedure()";
```

Calling like this from Java code is giving me **`400 bad`** request error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with Java spring-boot. The essential question is: can simultaneously given two queries within one string? Please test this:

```sql
"select 1 as a;select 2 as b;"
```

Can you obtain the "2"?
Great, then write a procedure which return a single value first and then test this:

```
"declare out int64;CALL my_dataset.my_stored_procedure(out);select out"
```

Otherwise, you need to save the result of the procedure in a table `my_dataset.my_stored_procedure_last_values` and query this table afterwards.